# How can I use consine distance with Local Sensitive Hashing?

Tags: mongodb, search-engine

Given my item (document) features (Bag of Words) extracted, I would like to implement a retrieval solution. My solution likes to use cosine distance with LSH. I searched internet and documentation but cannot find any trace to pre-built implementation natvei in MongoDB. Is there any way yo implement that onto MongoDB? Or what is your alternative?

Comment: First step is to make sure posts don't contain new terms.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your question? I have a similar problem with images hashed with phash and I want to reverse search for them.

Comment: I cannot find a solution based on Mongo then I implemented my file system.